# Toyota Avensis Central unlocking will only work when very hot outside

Tags: toyota, central-locking, avensis

I have an Avensis 11. The central locking works every time, but unlocking doesn't

It only unlocks the boot and turns the alarm off. Then I have to use the key to unlock the driver door, then the 3 other doors need unlocking manually.

UNLESS the day has been lovely and warm, or I have driven for about an hour then it will work ONCE and once only.

I took it to the Toyota garage and they told me I needed a new door lock, which had zero effect. My local dealer is about an hours drive away, so uses up a whole day going to them as I have to sit and wait for them to finish.

What could it be?

Comment: Was this resolved @WendyG? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Levi no my research says I need a new ECU (electronics control unit) which is getting expensive.

Comment: @levi where in the world are you, as it may be worth getting this seen together, as I know I am not alone. I am in the UK

Comment: UK too - London @WendyG

Comment: @Levi, up north, I wonder if this can be co-ordinated

Comment: Unlikely to be honest, @WendyG, although I guess it depends just how expensive it ends up being

Comment: we are talking £300+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92617/discussion-between-levi-and-wendyg).

Comment: WendyG did you ever get this sorted? My battery went flat and I took it out to charge. After putting the charged battery back in, the central unlocking now works most of the time.

Comment: @Levi, now that is weird, I have sort of abandoned it, it did start working (for a few weeks) a while ago, I wonder if it was related to my flat battery???

Comment: WendyG I just saw your chat messages from April - sorry my message from yesterday missed that context. I had stopped thinking about this issue too and may only update these comments to let anyone else know whether the problem naturally stays gone or comes back.

Comment: @Levi yes please let me know if it stays fixed.